# Understanding MCMC and the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

Over the past few days I have been trying to understand how Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) works. In particular I have been trying to understand and implement the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. So far I think I have an overall understanding of the algorithm but there are a couple of things that are not clear to me yet. I want to use MCMC to fit some models to data. Because of this I will describe my understanding of Metropolis-Hastings algorithm for fitting a straight line $f(x)=ax$ to some observed data $D$:

1) Make an initial guess for $a$. Set this $a$ as our current $a$ ($a_0$). Also add $a$ at the end of the Markov Chain ($C$).

2) Repeat the steps bellow a number of times.

3) Evaluate current likelihood (${\cal L_0}$) given $a_0$ and $D$.

4) Propose a new $a$ ($a_1$) by sampling from a normal distribution with $\mu=a_0$ and $\sigma=stepsize$. For now, $stepsize$ is constant.

5) Evaluate new likelihood (${\cal L_1}$) given $a_1$ and $D$.

6) If ${\cal L_1}$ is bigger than ${\cal L_0}$, accept $a_1$ as the new $a_0$, append it at the end of $C$ and go to step 2.

7) If ${\cal L_1}$ is smaller than ${\cal L_0}$ generate a number ($U$) in range [0,1] from a uniform distribution

8) If $U$ is smaller than the difference between the two likelihoods (${\cal L_1}$ - ${\cal L_0}$), accept $a_1$ as the new $a_0$, append it at the end of $C$ and go to step 2.

9) If $U$ is bigger than the difference between the two likelihoods (${\cal L_1}$ - ${\cal L_0}$), append the $a_0$ at the end of $C$, keep using the same $a_0$, go to step 2.

10) End of Repeat.

11) Remove some elements from the start of $C$ (burn-in phase).

12) Now take the average of the values in $C$. This average is the estimated $a$.

Now I have some questions regarding the above steps:

- How do I construct the likelihood function for $f(x)=ax$ but also for any arbitrary function?
- Is this a correct implementation of Metropolis-Hastings algorithm?
- How the selection of the random number generation method at Step 7 can change the results?
- How is this algorithm going to change if I have multiple model parameters? For example, if I had the model $f(x)=ax+b$.

Notes/Credits: The main structure of the algorithm described above is based on the code from an MPIA Python Workshop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There seem to be some misconceptions about what the Metropolis-Hastings (MH) algorithm is in your description of the algorithm.

First of all, one has to understand that MH is a sampling algorithm. As stated in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm)

> In statistics and in statistical physics, the Metropolis–Hastings algorithm is a Markov chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) method for obtaining a sequence of random samples from a probability distribution for which direct sampling is difficult.

In order to implement the MH algorithm you need a *proposal density* or *jumping distribution* $Q(\cdot\vert\cdot)$, from which it is easy to sample. If you want to sample from a distribution $f(\cdot)$, the MH algorithm can be implemented as follows:

1. Pick a initial random state $x_0$.
2. Generate a candidate $x^{\star}$ from $Q(\cdot\vert x_0)$.
3. Calculate the ratio $\alpha=f(x^{\star})/f(x_0)$.
4. Accept $x^{\star}$ as a realisation of $f$ with probability $\alpha$.
5. Take $x^{\star}$ as the new initial state and continue sampling until you get the desired sample size.

Once you get the sample you still need to *burn* it and *thin* it: given that the sampler works asymptotically, you need to remove the first $N$ samples (burn-in), and given that the samples are dependent you need to subsample each $k$ iterations (thinning).

An example in R can be found in the following link:

`http://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~ndjw1/teaching/sim/metrop/metrop.html`

This method is largely employed in Bayesian statistics for sampling from the posterior distribution of the model parameters.

The example that you are using seems unclear to me given that $f(x)=ax$ is not a density unless you restrict $x$ on a bounded set. My impression is that you are interested on fitting a straight line to a set of points for which I would recommend you to check the use of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm in the context of linear regression. The following link presents some ideas on how MH can be used in this context (Example 6.8):

[Robert & Casella (2010), *Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R*, Ch. 6, "Metropolis–Hastings Algorithms"](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781441915757-c1.pdf)

There are also lots of questions, with pointers to interesting references, in this site discussing about the meaning of likelihood function.

Another pointer of possible interest is the R package `mcmc`, which implements the MH algorithm with Gaussian proposals in the command `metrop()`.

Comment: Hi there my friend. Yes, I am looking into M-H in the context of linear regression. The url you gave me explains everything really nice. Thank you. If I come up with some other question regarding M-H I will post a question again. Thanks again.

Comment: Isn't $f(\cdot)$ an unknown distribution that you are trying to estimate?

If so, how do you compute $\alpha = f(x^*)/f(x_0)$